# CXF Logging request & response with content filtering or masking soap fields

Tags: java, logging, soap, cxf, filtering

I would like to log all incoming requests & responses from some particular endpoint, with content filtering. I.e. when i have a request like that:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope">
<soap:Body>
  <m:ProcessPhoto xmlns:m="http://www.w3schools.com/photos">
    <m:Name>Apples</m:Name>
    <m:Description>Photo with some apples in it</m:Description>
    <!-- large encoded binary below -->
    <m:Photo>anVzdCBhIHJhbmRvbSB0ZXh0DQpqdXN0IGEgcmFuZG9tIHRleHQNCmp1c3QgYSByYW5kb20gdGV4dA0KanVzdCBhIHJhbmRvbSB0ZXh0DQpqdXN0IGEgcmFuZG9tIHRleHQNCmp1c3QgYSByYW5kb20gdGV4dA0KanVzdCBhIHJhbmRvbSB0ZXh0DQp3b3csIGkgZGlkbid0IHRob3VnaHQgdGhhdCBhbnlvbmUgd291bGQgYmUgaW50ZXJlc3RlZCBpbiBkZWNvZGluZyB0aGlzLiBjb25ncmF0cyE=</m:Photo>
  </m:ProcessPhoto>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I would like to filter it, so that it looks in logs like that

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope">
<soap:Body>
  <m:ProcessPhoto xmlns:m="http://www.w3schools.com/photos">
    <m:Name>Apples</m:Name>
    <m:Description>Photo with some apples in it</m:Description>
    <m:Photo>hidden</m:Photo>
  </m:ProcessPhoto>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Or with completely removed m:Photo element.

I found that CXF has some LoggingInInterceptor and LoggingOutInterceptor and I could write my own interceptors that does that. However this would be a some work to do, so my question is: do you know any better, out of the box solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had similar problem, where I needed to mask passwords in my input request. I made a small change to existing LogginInterceptor and overridden format method and added my method to mask the password. Here is an example

```
public class CustomLogInInterceptor extends LoggingInInterceptor {

    @Override
    protected String formatLoggingMessage(LoggingMessage loggingMessage) {

        String str = loggingMessage.toString();

        String output = maskPasswords(str);
        return(output);
    }


    private String maskPasswords(String str) {

                final String[] keys = { "password", "passwords" };
                for (String key : keys) {
                    int beginIndex = 0;
                    int lastIndex = -1;
                    boolean emptyPass = false;
                    while (beginIndex != -1
                            && (beginIndex = StringUtils.indexOfIgnoreCase(str, key,
                                    beginIndex)) > 0) {

                        beginIndex = StringUtils.indexOf(str, ">", beginIndex);
                        if (beginIndex != -1) {
                            char ch = str.charAt(beginIndex - 1);
                            if (ch == '/') {
                                emptyPass = true;
                            }
                            if (!emptyPass) {
                                lastIndex = StringUtils.indexOf(str, "<", beginIndex);
                                if (lastIndex != -1) {
                                    String overlay = "*";
                                    String str2 = StringUtils.substring(str,
                                            beginIndex + 1, lastIndex);
                                    if (str2 != null && str2.length() > 1) {
                                        overlay = StringUtils.rightPad(overlay,
                                                str2.length(), "*");
                                        str = StringUtils.overlay(str, overlay,
                                                beginIndex + 1, lastIndex);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if (emptyPass) {
                                emptyPass = false;
                                lastIndex = beginIndex + 1;
                            } else {
                                if (lastIndex != -1) {
                                    lastIndex = StringUtils
                                            .indexOf(str, ">", lastIndex);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        beginIndex = lastIndex;
                    }
                }
                return str;

            }

}
```

And added custtom cxf logging bean in my cxf-bean.xml

```
<bean id="kpInInterceptor" class="com.kp.util.CustomLogInInterceptor" />

<cxf:bus>
        <cxf:inInterceptors>
            <ref bean="kpInInterceptor" />
        </cxf:inInterceptors>
        <cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
            <ref bean="kpInInterceptor" />
        </cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
</cxf:bus>
```

**Note** I've used Apache commons-lang3 jar for String manipulation. Similarly you can use for response as well

---

### UPDATE

**using Patterns and making keys configurable using properties.**

Interceptor

```
public class CustomLogInInterceptor extends LoggingInInterceptor {

    private static final String MASK_PATTERN = "<\\s*{}\\s*>(.*)</\\s*{}\\s*>|<\\s*name\\s*>\\s*{}\\s*</\\s*name\\s*>\\s*<\\s*value\\s*>(.*)<";

    private Pattern pattern;

    private String[] keys;

    public void init() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String str : keys) {
            builder.append(MASK_PATTERN.replace("{}", str));
            builder.append("|");
        }
        builder.setLength(builder.length()-1);
        pattern = Pattern.compile(builder.toString(), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE);
    }

    public void setKeys(String[] keys) {
        this.keys = keys;
    }


    @Override
    protected String formatLoggingMessage(LoggingMessage loggingMessage) {

        String output = maskPasswords(loggingMessage.toString());
        return(output);
    }


    private String maskPasswords(String str) {

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(str);
        while (matcher.find()) {

            int group = 1;
            while (group <= matcher.groupCount()) {
                if (matcher.group(group) != null) {
                    for (int i = matcher.start(group); i < matcher.end(group); i++) {
                        builder.setCharAt(i, '*');
                    }
                }
                group++;
            }
        }
        return builder.toString();

    }

}
```

**Bean creation**

```
<bean id="kpInInterceptor" class="com.kp.util.CustomLogInInterceptor" init-method="init">
    <property name="keys">
        <array value-type="java.lang.String">
            <value>password</value>
            <value>accountId</value>
        </array>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Sample Input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
    <hello>adffas</hello>
    <vsdsd>dfsdf</vsdsd>
    <password>sdfsfs</password>
    <sdfsfsf>sdfsfsf</sdfsfsf>
    <password>3434</password>
    <name>password</name>
    <value>sdfsfs</value>
    <password />
    <name>password</name>
    <value />
    <accountId>123456</accountId>
    <hello>
        <inner1>
            <password>
                <password>sdfsfs</password>
            </password>
        </inner>
    </hello>
</test>
```

**And the output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
    <hello>adffas</hello>
    <vsdsd>dfsdf</vsdsd>
    <password>******</password>
    <sdfsfsf>sdfsfsf</sdfsfsf>
    <password>****</password>
    <name>password</name>
    <value>******</value>
    <password />
    <name>password</name>
    <value />
    <accountId>******</accountId>
    <hello>
        <inner1>
            <password>
                <password>******</password>
            </password>
        </inner>
    </hello>
</test>
```

Comment: I would override this method instead: `String transform(String originalLogString)` the Javadoc for it explicitly says that it is the one to override for filtering the message.

Comment: Is there an updated way to do this using the new org.apache.cxf.ext.logging.LoggingInInterceptor since org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor was deprecated in v3.2?

Comment: does anyone have a way to do it using the new version of cxf?

Comment: Yup, you can get it here: https://gist.github.com/poznachowski/0bfc5ab19bb8e29e6a60e77a8c22c533
Usage is as simple as: `loggingFeature.setSender(ContentFilteringSlf4jEventSender.of(INFO, Set.of("ns2:password")));`

Answer (score 1):

I have written an open source library aimed at effectively pretty-printing SOAP messages: [xml-formatter-components-cxf](https://github.com/greenbird/xml-formatter-components/tree/master/cxf). Features include:

- High-performance reformatting of XML
- Advanced filtering options

  - Max text and/or CDATA node sizes
  - Reformatting of XML within text and/or CDATA nodes
  - Anonymize of element and/or attribute contents
  - Removal of subtrees

complete configuration [reference for spring](https://github.com/greenbird/xml-formatter-components/blob/master/spring.cheat.sheet.md).

Edit: The above library has been refactored to a more [generic library](https://github.com/skjolber/xml-log-filter) which probably is better for most normal use-cases, i.e. no XML wrapped in XML.

Comment: Only support for SOAP? Any plans to support JSON messages or any other format?

Comment: I'm considering making a JSON equivalent, more along the lines of the library linked in the edit.

Comment: Better late than never, I've created https://github.com/skjolber/json-log-filter

Comment: Perfect, great! .... Why did I need this again? xD I think I ended up with a home-made solution, but thanks for the update!