# Custom Logging Interceptor is not getting triggered

Tags: spring, apache, cxf

We are developing a RESTFUL services in spring framework and the log framework we are using is apache CXF.

We get the request in the form of JSON from the consumers of our services and we need to mask some of the contents of JSON before printing in the log files.

We are trying to have a custom interceptor to intercept the logger messages but the request never reaches the custom interceptor class. Can you please provide your thoughts to resolve the issue.

Below are the additional details :

```
public class CustomLogInterceptor extends LoggingInInterceptor {

    public String transform(String originalLogString) {

        // Custom logic will be here to mask the originalLogString

     }
}
```

spring context XML changes:

The `CustomLogInterceptor` class is included in the spring context XML file.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212313/cxf-logging-request-response-with-content-filtering-or-masking-soap-fields/23214151#23214151 please chechhere

Comment: Have you defined the `<property name="interceptors">` in the handler mapping?