# apache cxf LoggingFeature mask senstive information

Tags: java, logging, cxf

I'm using Logging feature to log in/out message to my cxf rest server on Spring boot. Similarly using the same to log outward Rest API connections initiated by cxf WebClient.

I came across few parameters which I do not want to be logged in to the log file. either completely removing them or masking them is sufficient for my case.

I found on the internet that previous (now depreciated) LoginIntercepter had transform operation to modify the log entry. I was not able to find a solution to mask/truncate the log entries wirg LoggingFeature.

any help would be appreciated

Current configuration of the server's logging feature is like below.

```
factory.setProviders(providers);
LoggingFeature loggingFeature = new LoggingFeature();
loggingFeature.setPrettyLogging(true);
loggingFeature.setLogBinary(false);
loggingFeature.setLogMultipart(false);
factory.getFeatures().add(loggingFeature);
Server server = factory.create();
```

web client configuration is as below

```
 LoggingFeature loggingFeature = new LoggingFeature();
loggingFeature.setPrettyLogging(true);
WebClient client = WebClient.create(url, Collections.singletonList(new JacksonJsonProvider()),
    Arrays.asList(loggingFeature), null);
```

Comment: Here is an example I had written long back, though it for xml, you can take a cue out of it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212313/cxf-logging-request-response-with-content-filtering-or-masking-soap-fields/23214151#23214151

Comment: See here for the solution to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57378998/4151472

Answer (score 2):

To change the log message, you can ...

> Write a custom LogSender and set it on the LoggingFeature to do custom
>   logging. All meta data can be access[ed] from the class LogEvent.

(Source: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/message-logging.html)

With a sender like:

```
// ...
import org.apache.cxf.ext.logging.event.LogEvent;

class MyLogEventSender implements org.apache.cxf.ext.logging.event.LogEventSender {

    @Override
    public void send(LogEvent event) {
       event.setPayload(maskSensibleParameters(event.getPayload()));
    }

    private String maskSensibleParameters(String pIn) {
       // here goes the tricky part 
       // ... but no details on this in your question 
       // ... here you can stick to "old" LogInterceptor examples
       // ... and also to PrettyLoggingFilter.
    }
}
```

A code example is given by (the default) [PrettyLoggingFilter](https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/3.1.x-fixes/rt/features/logging/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/ext/logging/event/PrettyLoggingFilter.java).

To mask (hide) it (completely) is easier and guaranteed more performant, it depends on the used "logging framework" (java.util, log4j or slf4j) and accomplished with an according "logger configuration". ([see here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/general-cxf-logging.html))