# Apache CXF LoggingInInterceptor is deprecated - what to use instead?

Tags: java, logging, cxf, interceptor

I am using Apache CXF with Spring Boot with the help of `cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws` plugin of version 3.2.7.

My intention is to customize the LoggingInterceptors but when I created the below class:

```
public class CustomLoggingInInterceptor extends org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor {}
```

but my IDE strikes out the LoggingInInterceptor complaining it's deprecated with the explanation

> use logging module rt/features/logging instead

So how should one go about customizing the logging interceptor using this module ?

Comment: I added a bit more details to the answer. I think they should be sufficient.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

What this message is telling you, is to use the `Apache CXF Advanced logging feature` module.

Its dependency is (latest version)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-features-logging</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Inside you'll find a comparable `org.apache.cxf.ext.logging.LoggingInInterceptor` ([link](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/ext/logging/LoggingInInterceptor.html))

---

I'm not a CXF user, however I suppose you'll have to interact with a `JaxWsProxyFactoryBean`.
Remember you need to use the same version for all the CXF modules.

After getting an hold on it, you can do

```
factory.getInInterceptors().add(new MyCustomInterceptor());
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Though, the API has changed it seems. Gonna have to figure out how to replace the removed methods such as  `formatLoggingMessage()`. Please feel free to share further info on migrating to this new module. Cheers

Comment: @dashboard look for `PrintWriterEventSender` and at the source code if `LoggingInInterceptor` https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/rt/features/logging/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/ext/logging/LoggingInInterceptor.java

Comment: @dashboard look also at second constructor and the last line of `LoggingInInterceptor#handleMessage`

Comment: For anyone wondering how to use this from a Spring XML config, here is an example: https://cxf.apache.org/docs/message-logging.html#MessageLogging-ManualUsage Basically, one needs to define `<bean class="org.apache.cxf.ext.logging.LoggingFeature"/>` inside the `jaxws:features` section.

Comment: thx. found your answer after a whole day of searching. And it's needed to add just one dependency...

Comment: @Filomat I know that feeling :P Glad this was helpful.

Answer (score 16):

Basically 4 things are needed to update from the old to the new cxf logging (rt/features/logging).

First, Set the logging feature:

```
final JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
factory.setFeatures(Collections.singletonList(new CustomLoggingFeature()));
```

You don't need anymore the interceptors (in case you used them, delete them):

<s>`factory.getInInterceptors().add(new CustomMaskedLoggingInInterceptor());`
`factory.getOutInterceptors().add(new CustomMaskedLoggingOutInterceptor());`</s>

Second, create your LoggingFeature:

```
public class CustomLoggingFeature extends org.apache.cxf.ext.logging.LoggingFeature {
    public CustomLoggingFeature() {
        super();
        this.setSender(new CustomEventLogSender());
    }
}
```

Third, create your EventLogSender:

```
public class CustomEventLogSender extends Slf4jVerboseEventSender {
    @Override
    protected String getLogMessage(LogEvent event) {
        String logMessage = super.getLogMessage(event);
        return CustomMasker.mask(logMessage);
    }
}
```

Fourth, create a CustomMasker class where you have your own string manipulation logic to mask the desired information.

Let me know if it worked!

Comment: Thank you for the input, will try as soon as got time. If this works you'd be answered the second part of the question, however I can only choose one answer. Maybe you can update the answer so it has two sections one for existing and one for your answer ?

Comment: Well the thing is that with the new cxf logging you don't customize the `LoggingInInterceptor` class, instead you do the things I described above. Or maybe I didn't understand your comment? What information exactly is missing?

Comment: There's no information missing, i thought that it'd be better if you were to be so kind to update the accepted answer so it contains your part too, that's all :)

Answer (score 4):

When you have this elsewhere mentioned dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-features-logging</artifactId>
    <version>${org.apache.cxf.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

and when you work with a `JaxWsProxyFactoryBean`, you can configure that factory e.g. like this:

```java
LoggingFeature loggingFeature = new LoggingFeature();
loggingFeature.setPrettyLogging(true);
loggingFeature.setVerbose(true);
loggingFeature.setLogMultipart(true);
factory.getFeatures().add(loggingFeature);
```

Answer (score 1):

The new imports for this class are :

```java
import org.apache.cxf.ext.logging.LoggingInInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.ext.logging.LoggingOutInterceptor;
```

which could be found in the `org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-features-logging` dependency.

Please refer to this question for [code snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60948591/payload-format-apache-cxf-soap-messages).

Comment: Appreciated your comment, though this was already answered and accepted.