# Masking Sensitive Data in CXF Logging SOAP Requests

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, soap, cxf

After using CXF to call a SOAP webservice, CXF client logs the SOAP request message with password visible! I want to hide sensitive data like passwords from the CXF client logging.

Here's what I got in log:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <runReport xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/oxp/service/MYSERVICE">
       <userID>username</userID>
       <password>mypassword</password>
    </runReport>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

All I want is to replace `mypassword` to `**********`

I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212313/cxf-logging-request-response-with-content-filtering-or-masking-soap-fields/23214151) but it won't work with my CXF version because it uses an older version of CXF.

I really saw many examples, ones that extends LoggingOutInterceptor, other extends AbstractSoapInterceptor, other extends PhaseInterceptorChain and others... and I really don't know where to start, I couldn't find any documentation on this matter.

Any help, link to doc will be appreciated!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Cheers!

Comment: Nope, I don't work on this project anymore, but I still wanna know how to deal with it!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this extending LoggingInInterceptor and adding the words that i want to hide in the method addSensitiveElementNames, for header they have sensitiveProtocolHeaderNames method to do the same.

```
  public class MyLogIn extends LoggingInInterceptor {
    
      public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
         addSensitiveElementNames(Set.of("description"));
         super.handleMessage(message);
      }
 }
```

I found some info in this [site](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/message-logging.html)

Comment: I can't find the method addSensitiveElementNames, although I'm using the latest version of Apache CXF (3.4.3). Where did you find that?

Comment: I found it on the LoggingFeature class, you can add a list of them to the SpringBus.